# Unable to create mfp cordova project in Android 28

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, android-sdk-tools, mfp

Latest Android SDK is not letting me use android command, as it is deprecated to create a `mfp cordova` project.

I'm using `IBM MobileFirst CLI v7.1.0.00.20180706-0858` and latest `Android SDK & Android Studio`.
May I know any work around to create a project with `mfp cordova`?

**Updated**

***Steps to reproduce the issue:***

1) Download and install the latest `Android Studio` and download the latest `Android SDK` using `sdkmanager`. Set the system variables to the downloaded SDK buildtools and tools.

2) Download and install the latest `MFP CLI v7.1.0.00.20180706-0858`.

3) Run `mfp cordova create` in the command line and the following error happens.

[MFP cordova project create Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhFib.png)

[Android Deprecated Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01q1W.png)

Thank you

Comment: You seem to have the latest Android SDK tools ? With the version of Cordova that is in 7.1 , it uses android.

Comment: Can you  share the steps ,in the screen shots provided does not show which mfp command you are performing.Pleas add steps to recreate the issue.

Comment: Yes @VivinK. I was planning to develop a test mfp cordova app targeting the latest android API 28 with mfp 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileFirst CLI contains an instance of Cordova CLI v5.0.0, Android platform version 3.6.4.For more details see here :

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/

Cordova-Android@3.6.4  works only with older tools of android such as Android target: android-23.In your case you have updated your platform tools to latest that is why you are seeing such error.

I have uploaded older tools of android here :
https://ibm.box.com/s/je74bzx73y6je65tdnpttyns4ih1zj7b

Rename or take back up of your existing tools in android sdk path.Put uploaded tools in android sdk path.

With Android P that is targeting to API 28 with MobileFirst 7.1 app ,you may face an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/params/BasicHttpParams;

Work around is to add below tag in AndroidManifest.xml inside the  tag:

[Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779)

The same has been update in the 
[Android P blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/07/05/mobilefirst-android-P/#known-issues)